# java byte vs c++ BYTE

Tags: java, c++, image-processing, run-length-encoding

I know Java `byte` range is -128 to 127, but C++ `BYTE` is a `unsigned char` (0 to 255.)

I want to convert a C++ function to Java, and in C++ I have a `LPBYTE` (which is a pointer to `BYTE` array.) I've tried using `byte` array instead of `LPBYTE` in C++ function, but my Java function is still not working correctly.

My C++ function works on a BMP file and it's algorithm is customized run length encoding. In converting it to Java I'm using a `BufferedImage` and getting its content as `byte[]`. I'm guessing the Java function is not working correctly because of type mismatch.

Which type should I use in Java?

Comment: There's no standard type `BYTE` in C++. It's a typedef/define, usually `unsigned char`, but it could be `char` so far.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Java you can use a plain `byte` and convert to an `int` as required with `b & 0xFF`

The problem you have is that *Java does not support pointers* and you cannot pass a pointer to bytes to Java.  The nearest equivalent is `byte[]`.

If you are only doing RLE encoding, the actual value of the bytes is not important so it doesn't matter whether they are signed or unsigned.  If you are decoding a BMP file you can use the mask as above as required.

When reading/writing to a byte array, a common solution is to use a ByteBuffer.  This supports writing longer types such as `short` or `int` in little endian or big endian order and you don't need to know the exact length in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Java has no unsigned types (apart from  `char` which is 16 bits). So you have no choice, pick `byte` but rewrite your code so it works with signed integers. If you need help with this *post the code*.

Answer (score 1):

There is no unsigned byte type in Java. You could use `short` instead. This can represent all values from 0 to 255, and more.

Comment: actually i have to use BufferedImage , because i am using ByteArrayOutputStream to get file content and it is returning byte[] so i have to read content byte by byte and cast it to short , am I right ?